# Delete empty rows in one-to-many relationship (postgresql)

Tags: database, postgresql, one-to-many

Table book (book_id, title) is the main table.
Table book_version (version_id, book_id,publisher) is another table

book_id is primary key to the **book** and foreign key (on update cascade on delete cascade) to **book_version**. They have a one-to-many relationship, since there may be several versions of the same book

Obviously, to delete all versions of a book: `DELETE FROM book WHERE book_id = $some_id`

However, if I want to delete a specific version we have two cases:

1. There are several versions of this book, so just delete entry based on version_id:  `DELETE FROM book_version WHERE version_id = $some_id`
2. There is one single version so far. Not only the row in the **book_version** has to be deleted, but also the row in the **book** table

I know it can be done using count (I count the number of rows in book_version. If it is more than one, go to case 1. Else go to case 2). But I'd like to make this happen in a single query, without including two different queries or (if possible) an if statement. Maybe I could do something in the database structure - it doesn't have to be because of the query. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in a single plain SQL query. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0305f/1)

```
with dv as (
    delete from book_version
    where version_id = 2
    returning book_id, version_id
)
delete from book b
using dv
where
    b.book_id = dv.book_id
    and
    not exists (
        select version_id
        from book_version
        where
            book_id = dv.book_id
            and
            version_id != dv.version_id
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm - exactly how I intended it. Although I would have preferred to find some challenge or mistake, so that I don't feel useless.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a trigger could be used here.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteIfLastVersionIsDeleted AFTER DELETE ON book_version ...
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I have never used triggers before (shame on me , i know). But I will check it out and let you know.